# Call a function if a valid URL is found in a textarea

Tags: javascript, regex, url

What would be the best way to immediately call a function (myFunction()) as soon as a valid URL has been typed into a textfield? I've googled around but I haven't found anything that helps. Using a regular expression would probably be best but I need one that recognizes all sorts of URLs:
http://google.tld, www.google.tld, http://www.google.tld 
But still doesn't consider things like "index.php" to be a URL. Does anyone know about such an expression?

Comment: Please don't put tags in the title.

Comment: *google.com* vs *index.php* is tricky, because the only way to know that the former is a URL is to have a list of valid TLDs in the regex itself, making it slow and complicated.  Such a list would also need to be updated as new TLDs are added, so it's higher maintenance.  You should make `http://` a requirement.

Comment: @Andy E: Yeah, I figured, and actually that isn't *that* important. As long as it recognizes www.google.com, ht tp://www.google.com and ht tp://google.com, I'm happy.

Comment: Do you need to be able to recognize full URLs, too?  Including path and query parameters?  Hashtag?  (Like ht tp://google.com/search?q=call-a-function-if-a-valid-url-is-found-in-a-textarea#res )

Comment: @Martijn Yeah, probably.

Comment: "Oh man, I tried to type in google.com but the function fired when I typed in google.co!" (Yes, .co is a valid domain, so somehow you need to handle this case too)

Answer (score 0):

this will match any URL that ends with something like '.com' or '.ch' (you have to maintain the list of valid TLDs)

```
^(http:\/\/)?([\w\.]+\.)((com)|(ch))$
```

with javascript the forwardslash doesn't need escaping and TLDs could be less strict e.g. just something with 2-4 characters.

```
^(https?://)?([\w\.]+\.)([a-z]{2,4})$
```

Considering a comment to this question by CanSpice the idea of allowing TLDs with different length is difficult to cover as the event trigger may fire too early. A time delay upon the onchange trigger may solve this kind of issues.
Precise requirements and pros/cons of each solution should be weighted.

[example at rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/zAmpfSozwW)

Comment: Thanks, but that only works for .com domains. It'd need to work for all domains. Please see my above comment, too:

"@Andy E: Yeah, I figured, and actually that isn't that important. As long as it recognizes www.google.com, ht tp://www.google.com and ht tp://google.com, I'm happy. "

Comment: @Holoradius: you asked only for '.com' in the first place... hope my update helps to solve your problem

Comment: No, the URLs were only examples. I stated that it needs to recognize all sorts of URLs

Answer (score 0):

You might struggle a bit as there would be so many different possibilities. This one will match any url that is technically a valid http or https path (which includes any character in the path after the domain name, any number of subdomains, etc)

```
((http)s?(://))?[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*(/(.*))?
```

Of if you'd like to exclude intranets, you can force a tld using the following:

```
((http)s?(://))?[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+(/(.*))?
```

Answer (score 0):

^((?:https?|ftp):\/\/)?([\w\.]+.)([a-z]{2,4})$

Supports ftp as well ;)